# SyntaxError: invalid syntax while using flask_wtf package

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

I tried to use the flask_wtf in my python2 script but i get this error

```
    File "bartender.py", line 16, in <module>
    from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_wtf/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .csrf import CSRFProtect, CsrfProtect
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 220
    dest = f'{view.__module__}.{view.__name__}'
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

here is my import line

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request, redirect, url_for
from multiprocessing import Process
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import NumberRange, Length
```

I know python3 is out and we should use this but this is a very ols script from me and i tried to extend it and I also do a python3 portation :)

Comment: That's an `f string` and isn't available in Python 2.

Comment: and how to avoid this?

Comment: Update to python 3 or pin your dependencies to a version that doesn't need python 3

Comment: how do I downgrade to flask_wtf for python2?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
pip install flask-wtf==0.14.3
```

Comment: Please explain why this would help. [edit] the post